# Disable Orientation Change while recording Video

Tags: android, orientation, mediarecorder

Does anyone know how to disable Orientation change while recording ?

I tried something like this, but no success. any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (!recordingAudio && !recordingVideo) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it by adding the following in the manifest file as an attribute of the `activity` tag:

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```